# A basic Monoid definition gives "No instance for (Semigroup MyMonoid) arising from the superclasses of an instance declaration"

Tags: haskell, monoids

I am attempting to define Haskell integer sets with the union operation as a [Monoid](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html).

```
module MyMonoid where

import qualified Data.IntSet as S

data MyMonoid = MyMonoid S.IntSet

instance Monoid MyMonoid where
  mempty = MyMonoid S.empty
  MyMonoid m1 `mappend` MyMonoid m2 = MyMonoid (S.union m1 m2)
```

I get the error

```
• No instance for (Semigroup Markup)
    arising from the superclasses of an instance declaration
• In the instance declaration for ‘Monoid MyMonoid’
```

What am I doing wrong? This seems so simple, and I'm copying the syntax I see in examples like [this](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/user/mgsloan/monoids-tour), but I can't see why this error is occurring.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Since that tour was written, `(<>)` has been moved from Monoid to Semigroup, and all Monoid instances are required to also be Semigroup. `mappend` is just a synonym for `(<>)`. So, you need two instances:

```
instance Semigroup MyMonoid where
  MyMonoid m1 <> MyMonoid m2 = MyMonoid (S.union m1 m2)

instance Monoid MyMonoid where
  mempty = MyMonoid S.empty
```